# Cannot deserialize the json file with list of events?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have below C# class structure,

```
public class Event
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    public BodyProperty[] BodyProperties { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public string CreatedTime { get; set; }
}

public class BodyProperty
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public Body(string value, string type = "TextualBody", string format = "application/json")
    {
        Type = type;
        Value = value;
        Format = format;
    }

    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}
```

and trying to read below JSON file,

```
{
    "Events": [
        {
            "Id": "d22fc23c-968f-4406-bebb-fca231694986",
            "Body": {
                "Type": "TextualBody",
                "Value": "test",
                "Format": "application/json"
            },
            "BodyProperties": null,
            "EventType": "Entity",
            "CreatedTime": "2020-02-20T13:57:14.1234165+05:30"
        },
        {
            "Id": "fgdgdg-968f-4406-bebb-646464",
            "Body": {
                "Type": "TextualBody",
                "Value": "test",
                "Format": "application/json"
            },
            "BodyProperties": null,
            "EventType": "Entity",
            "CreatedTime": "2020-02-21T13:57:14.1234165+05:30"
        }
    ]
}
```

But this give below error while trying to read like this, I can't change JSON format, what can I change while reading?

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\TEMP\json1.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader jsonreader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return serializer.Deserialize<List<Event>>(jsonreader);
        }
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[uploadJSON.Event]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your JSON class structure is:

```
public class Body
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    public object BodyProperties { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize to `RootObject` type.

On site [json2csharp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) or in VS you can generate classes from JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `RootObject`

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you code should look like :

```
public class Body
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Body Body { get; set; }
    public object BodyProperties { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
}

public class ListOfEvents
{
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}
```

Finally

```
using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"C:\TEMP\json1.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader jsonreader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            return serializer.Deserialize<List<ListOfEvents>>(jsonreader);
        }
```